# C# Possible To Serialise Enum description instead Enum value With Json

Tags: c#, json, enums

I have the situation where I am receiving a response from two different web services. The two responses are identical in structure, but have different parent namespaces. What I am trying to do is convert these responses into a standard class I can then pass out to the parent object. I figured the simplest way was to Serialize the incoming object to Json, and then Deserialize the object into my standard object. This keeps my processing code rather simple

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serviceResponse.Results);
var commonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StandardResult>(jsonString);
```

And for the most part this is working. However I'm expanding the StandardResult object I've discovered a bit of a problem.

One of the properties of the object is a class with the following properties:

```
public class EntryDetailType
{
public string EntryNumber {get; set;}
public string EntryText {get; set;
public int Item {get; set;}
}
```

The issue is that `Item` can actually be one of two different enums in the incoming data. So although the conversion is correctly putting the enum's value in `Item` I have no idea which enum that value refers to. I'm not at this stage using a JsonConverter class as the object is very large and I wanted to avoid that if possible.

Is there a method of being able to get the enum's description instead of the value as part of this process, or am I going to be forced to write my own json converters? Please bear in mind that the `EntryDetailType` class is not in my project. It is the return type from a web service that has been added via a wsdl document.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the enum's description" - do you mean you want the *name representation* of the value rather than the *integer representation* of the value? (Both are values.)

Comment: Yes @JonSkeet that is what I mean

Comment: So do you want `EntryDetailType` to have a member `public string Item {get; set;}` instead?  Or `public System.Enum Item {get; set;}`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the class `EntryDetailType` really has a property named `Item` of type `int`, it is not possible to infer which name representation value of the `enum` you have.

But, if this class has a property `Item` of any `enum` type, then it is as easy as serializing to Json using the built-in `StringEnumConverter` as the second parameter of the SerializeObject method:

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serviceResponse.Results, new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
```

*ps: I'm assuming you are using the Json.NET from NewtonSoft.*